# "the unfamiliarity with" or "unfamiliarity with"?

Tags: grammar, articles

I always have a lack of confidence in using the articles (a/an/the).

I want to write one of the following sentences in my paper. But I don't know which one is more appropriate? Could you please help me?

> **The** unfamiliarity with these social protocols can have severe consequences.

or

> Unfamiliarity with these social protocols can have severe consequences.

Comment: It depends perhaps totally on whether this unfamiliarity has already been alluded to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your **second** sentence is perfectly idiomatic.

The unfamiliarity here is a **human attribute**. So you might also say, "*Our unfamiliarity with....*" or "*One's unfamiliarity with...*"

But in "*The unfamiliarity **of** the room kept the child awake,*" unfamiliarity is an **attribute of the room itself**.

So you *could* make unfamiliarity a characteristic of the protocols themselves by saying, "*The unfamiliarity **of** these social protocols can have severe consequences*". But don't! Your second sentence is perfect.